# Changing the java.home path in VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I just installed java 11 coz VS code was prompting me to update it to java 11 or newer version. After installing java 14, I'm not getting how to change the path to new folder that has java 14.
In settings.json file the path can be seen when cursor hovered over java.home variable.
[image: Image attached] [image: image attached 1]

Comment: Environment variables, more specifically the `PATH` variable.

Comment: @nbokmans yes I've changed it there, 
Here's output from cmd
C:\Users\Lenovo>echo %PATH%
...C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;e:\anconda;e:\anconda\Library\mingw-w64\bin;e:\anconda\Library\usr\bin;e:\anconda\Library\bin;e:\anconda\Scripts;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm;F:\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.1\bin;

Answer (score 31):

For those coming now, in VSCode settings change "java.home" to "java.jdt.ls.java.home"

From

```
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.2"
```

To

```
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.2",
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for info, however I was unable to find a reason for this change. Could you please provide more info?

Comment: "settings.json file" : where can I find this file?

Comment: @MouseNag When you go to File -> Preferences -> Settings, there is an icon on the top right corner which says "Open Settings (JSON)" when you hover over it.

Comment: Reason:  `"java.home"` is deprecated.

Answer (score 9):

The path to the Java Development Kit is searched in the [following order](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#setting-the-jdk):

1. the java.home setting in VS Code settings (workspace then user
   settings)
2. the JDK_HOME environment variable
3. the JAVA_HOME environment variable
4. on the current system path

The 'java.home' has the highest priority, and 'java.home' is different from the system environment variable. Open settings and search 'java.home', you can get the example:

```
"java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_161"
```

It points to 'jdk' folder instead of 'jdkFolder\bin'.

Comment: it says it's deprecated, any update on the new way ?

Comment: the java.home setting in VS Code settings (workspace then user settings) where can I find this file?