# How do I set up JDK in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've tried setting up VS Code so many times. But it just does not point to the right shady path. I think I messed up something in one of the previous installations.

So now every time I just try to run a Java program, this is the error that pops up.
Is there any way I can fix this by making some changes in the settings?

I've also installed the extension which is a complete package for Java development in VS Code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped me :

You can try following this.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial

---

Also, try going to settings in VSCode. Search for jdk, it opens up a settings.json file. Now try this.

And sheck this :
[Changing the java.home path in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057245/changing-the-java-home-path-in-vs-code)