# Visual Studio Code Will not Install Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am Currently running VSCode 1.85.0 and it seems that no matter what I do, VSCode refuses to run any Java code. I successfully installed the VScode Java coding pack from

[code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20run%20Java,Amazon%20Corretto)

I also downloaded all of the Java extensions that were recommended. However, when I search Java: Create Java Project, nothing pops up. When I try to run

```
public class QuickStart{
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

}

Nothing happens. When I run this same code from the command line directly, it runs without issue. When I type in Java --version in the command line I get

```
openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9) OpenJDK
64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.9+9 (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode,
sharing)
```

So it appears Java has been installed correctly but VSCode is unaffected and does not recognize it. I've tried manually deleting all of the extensions and reinstalling them but that also did not work. I am at a total loss. It seems like installing the extensions effectively does nothing. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I will fix the link. I did download the VSCode from that site though

Comment: So, what extension did you install? What java jdk did you install? DId you first try the recommended method: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java#_install-visual-studio-code-for-java

Comment: The documentation mentions this important point: *If you open a Java file in VS Code without opening its folder, the Java Language Server might not work properly.*

Comment: I installed Amazon Corretto. I restarted my PC and it works now.

Comment: [*Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/)

Answer (score 1):

### (Solution 1/2). It is possible that you have not yet set the JAVA_Home environment variable yet.

**(Windows)**

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
2. Click the Advanced system settings link.
3. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
4. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
5. Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

### (Solution 2/2). configure your "java.home" path in your settings.json file

Provide below is how to do so
[Changing the java.home path in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057245/changing-the-java-home-path-in-vs-code)

If neither of these solutions work, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Set the JDK path below and use Java to extend the execution script.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects*

```
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_341",
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.5",
            "default": true,
        }
    ],
```